# Working Laravel in CPanel but not in localhost without Artisan

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, cpanel

I've installed in my remote server, via Softaculous, Laravel 8.
In order to access directly to the APP, just like when running `php artisan serve` in my local machine, in CPanel i defined the document root to the folder Laravel\public.

Everything works exactly as it should! I type the address (ex: myDomain.com) and the App runs perfectly...

However i don't want to being always typing `php artisan serve` while developing, so i tried to replicate the cpanel struture in my local machine.
To achive thar, i've created a virtualhost in XAMPP httpd-vhosts.conf pointing to the folder Laravel\public, and created the host file in windows system, like always.

When accessing the location in my local machine the first page renders perfectly, but as soon as i make a request for a new view, by example:

```
Route::get('/posts', function () {
    return view('posts.index');
});
```

I get a "Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server" error! I'm sure is not a coding error because the same code runs flawlessly in remote server.

Which technique is used by cpanel to allow laravel to work directly from \public folder without necessity to initiate anything and how to replicate that in local development machine?

Answer (score 0):

Well...

After much reading, backs and forwards, i believe this behavior depends on the way Apache its served by XAMPP.
So, the solution i adopted was change my local development tool to LARAGON.
Everything worked just fine with a lot of new features that don´t exist in XAMPP.